# Reactive Form Angular and pass controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a question about good practise in Angular Reactive Forms.

I have custom component with input text:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label [for]="inputId" *ngIf="label">{{label | translate}}</label>
  <div>
    <input [formControl]="control" [id]="inputId" class="form-control">
  </div>
<div>
```

and in ts:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AbstractControl, Form, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, TranslateModule],
  templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.scss']
})
export class TextInput {

  @Input() inputId = '';
  @Input() control!: FormControl;
  @Input() label = '';
}
```

and I use it in parent component like below:
in html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
 <app-text-input [label]="'test'" [control]="getControl('test')" 
 [inputId]="'test'"></app-text-input>
</form>
```

and in ts

```js
getControl(control: string): FormControl {
  return <FormControl>this.form.get(field);
}

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  test: ['',
    [Validators.required],
  ],
});
```

Is it ok to use it like that? Because sometimes I see solutions with getters, where every controls have different getter eg:

```js
get test1(): FormControl { return this.form.get('test1') as FormControl};
get test2(): FormControl { return this.form.get('test1') as FormControl};
```

Is it some difference between these solutions, if we talk eg about not necessary detection or performance?

So related to comments - my app-text-input is custom component so I have to pass here my control. I use function getControl to do that and I just wonder that it's good solution for it.

Comment: Why don't you use ‍‍‍`formGroup` and `formControlName`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850069/how-to-wrap-custom-angular-material-Usecontrol-into-own-component/75853026?noredirect=1#comment133808014_75853026

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a `FormGroup` in my opinion the cleanest way to do it using the `FormControlName`

```
<app-text-input [label]="'test'" [formControlName]="'test'" [inputId]="'test'"></app-text-input>
```

Where your `form` will have the control name

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  test: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

The `fb` is the formBuilder in case that you are not familiar with it

Comment: I edited my post: app-text-input is my custom component where I have input and here I use [formControl] and pass my control.
And I don't ask about it, I ask about difference between call getters vs call function in html. Even for display errors: I

Answer (score 0):

I use reactives forms like this

someForm.ts

```
<form
  novalidate
  autocomplete='off'
  [formGroup]='this.parentForm'
>
  <app-input-text
    [parentForm]='this.someForm'
    [formCtrlName]="'search'" // => of course, it could be dynamic
  >
  </app-input-text>
</form>
```

app-input-text.ts

```
export class InputTextComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() formCtrlName: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

app-input-text.html

```
<form
  novalidate
  autocomplete='off'
  [formGroup]='this.parentForm'
>
  <input
    matInput
    [placeholder]='this.placeholder'
    [formControlName]='this.formCtrlName'
  >
</form>
```

I like split the compents more granular...
I this kind of way I can manipulate in parent form all validations...
Inputs can be very reusable, I used this way in many projects with very good results.

Comment: if use ViewProviders you needn't pass the FormGroup

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use viewProviders, like the first code in this
   [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850069/how-to-wrap-custom-angular-material-Usecontrol-into-own-component/75853026?noredirect=1#comment133808014_75853026).
2. In the same SO -althougth it's related to mat-input, you have
   another way passing the "formControlName" and inject the
   FormControlDirective.
3. Yes, the another way is pass the FormControl as Input. In this case
   use a "getter" in the Input, so you needn't use a getter of the
   control

   ```
   control!:FormControl
   @Input('control') _control(value:AbstractControl){
      this.control=value as FormControl
   }
   ```