# Angular + ASP.NET WebApi register form issues using Form Builder

Tags: html, json, validation, asp.net-web-api, angular-formbuilder

I try to create my first project but still facing many problems with Angular.
Currently I am busy with register form using Form Builder.

Firstly I paste my code:

- register component:

```js
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  //@Output() cancelRegister = new EventEmitter();
  registerForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  complexPassword = "(?=^.{8,20}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:;'?/&gt;.&lt;,])(?!.*\s).*$";
  errors: string[] | null = null;
  email: string;
  
  genders = [
    {value:GenderEnum.None, text:'Prefer not to say'},
    {value:GenderEnum.Male, text:'Male'},
    {value:GenderEnum.Female, text:'Female'},
    {value:GenderEnum.Other, text:'Others'}
];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private accountService: AccountService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeForm();
  }

  initializeForm() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
    displayName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.email],
      [this.validateEmailNotTaken()]],
    firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(20),
      Validators.pattern(this.complexPassword)]],
    dateOfBirth: [null],
    gender: [null],
    street: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    postalCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
    city: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, this.matchValues('password')]],
    });
    
    this.registerForm.controls['password'].valueChanges.subscribe({
    next: () => this.registerForm.controls['confirmPassword'].updateValueAndValidity()
    })
  }  

  matchValues(matchTo: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return control.value === control.parent?.get(matchTo)?.value ? null : {notMatching: true}
    }
  }

   passwordMatchValidator(group: AbstractControl) {
    return group.get('password').value === group.get('confirmPassword').value
      ? null : { mismatch: true };
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (!this.registerForm.valid)
      return;
  
    this.accountService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe({
      next: (response:any) => {
        if (response.error)
        {
          this.errors = response.error;
        }
        else
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/shop');
      },
      error: error => 
      {
        this.errors = error.errors
      }
    });
  }

  validateEmailNotTaken(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return control.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        take(1),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.email = control.value;
          return this.accountService.checkEmailExists(this.email).pipe(
            map(result => result ? {emailExists: true} : null),
            finalize(() => control.markAsTouched())
          )
        })
      )
    }
  }

  cancel() {
    //this.cancelRegister.emit(false);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/shop')
  }

  private getDateOnly(dob: string | undefined) {
    if (!dob) return;
    let theDob = new Date(dob);
    return new Date(theDob.setMinutes(theDob.getMinutes()-theDob.getTimezoneOffset()))
      .toISOString().slice(0,10);
  }
}
```

- register template:

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-3">
        <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="text-center mb-4">
                <h1 class="mb-3">Sign up</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label style="margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Gender (optional): 
                </label><br>
                <label *ngFor="let gender of genders" >
                    <ul>
                       <input type="radio" [value]="gender.value" formControlName="gender"> 
                            {{gender.text}}
                   </ul>
                 </label>               
            </div>

            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['displayName'])"
                [label]="'Display Name'"></app-text-input>
            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['email'])" [label]="'Email'"></app-text-input>
            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['password'])" [label]="'Password'"
                [type]="'password'"></app-text-input>
            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['confirmPassword'])" [label]="'Confirm Password'"
                [type]="'password'"></app-text-input>
            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['firstName'])"
                [label]="'First Name'"></app-text-input>
            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['lastName'])"
                [label]="'Last Name'"></app-text-input>
            <app-date-picker [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['dateOfBirth'])"
                [label]="'Date of Birth'"></app-date-picker>
            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['street'])" [label]="'Street'"></app-text-input>
            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['postalCode'])"
                [label]="'Postal Code'"></app-text-input>
            <app-text-input [formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['city'])" [label]="'City'"></app-text-input>

            <ul class="text-danger list-unstyled" *ngIf="errors">
                <li *ngFor="let error of errors">
                    {{error}}
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="text-center">
                <button [disabled]="registerForm.invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary my-3 me-4 col-5"
                    type="submit">Sign up</button>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-light my-3 col-5" type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

- account-service component

```js
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User | null>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();
  errorsAccount: string[] | null = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  loadCurrentUser(token: string | null) {
    if (token === null) {
      this.currentUserSource.next(null);
      return of(null);
    }

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account', {headers}).pipe(
      map((user: any) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.data.token);
          this.currentUserSource.next(user.data);
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  login(values: any) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', values).pipe(
      map((user: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.data.token);
        this.currentUserSource.next(user.data);
      })
    )
  }

  register(values: any) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/register', values).pipe(
      tap((res:any) => {
        if (!res.error)
        {
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
          this.currentUserSource.next(res.data);
        }
      })
    )
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.currentUserSource.next(null);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }

  checkEmailExists(email: string) {
    return this.http.get<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'account/emailExists?EmailToCheck=' + email);
  }
}
```

Problems:

1. How to send Gender as integer in Form Builder form that will be accepted by backend and database?
   Because now it is sending as string.
   `"gender": "2"` instead of `"gender": 2`
2. I am trying to display Gender Enum items as radio buttons which can be chosen by user by they are duplicated in template. How to fix it?

[image: Register form]

3. In backend I have implemented checking whether provided email is already in use.
   Unfortunately when email is already taken I cannot display response from backend in frontend.
   [image: server resposne]

DevTools/Network/Payload:

[image: payload]

I tried to wrap object which I am getting back from API in (object: any).

When I provide free email I got response like this:

```
{
  "data":
  {
     "displayName":"Thomas",
     "dateOfBirth":null,
     "gender":null,
     "email":"tom@test2.com",
     "token":"someTokenGenerated"
   },
   "error":null
}
```

Gender and Date of Birth are optional properties.

Please understand I'm not a professional developer but keeping learning.

Sorry for maybe redundant amount of code but I wanted to clarify my issues as much as it possible.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

EDIT:

After changes according to Eliseo answer I got still some issues:

[image]

But [value] works as well - binding numbers to gender.

In register form when I am typing email which already exists (adam@test.com) still not displaying under the email label that the "email is already taken".

Answer (score 1):

The enums in .ts are "complicates", see, e.g. this [link about it](https://www.petermorlion.com/iterating-a-typescript-enum/) you can use in .ts a simple array

```
genders = [
           {value:GenderEnum.None,text:''},
           {value:GenderEnum.Male,text:'Male},
           {value:GenderEnum.Female,text:'Female'},
           {value:GenderEnum.Other,text:'Others'}
]
```

And use ngValue instead value

```
<label .. *ngFor="let gender of genders" >
   <ul>
      <input type="radio" [ngValue]="gender.value" formControlName="gender"> 
           {{gender.text}}
  </ul>
</label>
```

Or use Object.keys and filter directly and the index (this works well because the first element gets the value 0 and you're using enum with numbers)

```
genders=Object.keys(GenderEnum).filter((x:any)=>isNaN(x))

<label .. *ngFor="let gender of genders;let i=index" >
   <ul>
      <input type="radio" [ngValue]="i" formControlName="gender"> 
           {{gender}}
  </ul>
</label>
```

Your submit can take account when the API return the "error". Be careful, the response is ok

```
onSubmit() {
  //check if is valid before send
  if (!this.registerForm.valid)
       return;

  this.accountService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe({
    next: (response:any) => {
       if (response.error)
       {
           //do something, e.g. alert(response.error)
           //or this.error=response.error
       }
       else
           this.router.navigateByUrl('/shop'),
    }
    error: error => 
    {
      this.errors = error.errors
  }
  });
```

}

But your service should return the "error"

```
register(values: any) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/register', values).pipe(
      tap((res:any) => {
        if (!res.error)
        {
           //store "res.data.token"
           localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
           this.currentUserSource.next(res.data);
        }
       })
    )
  }
```

NOTE: use "tap" instead of "map" if you needn't change the response of an Observable.

NOTE2: I see many `[formControl]="$any(registerForm.controls['email'])"`. You can make that your app-text-inputs becomes like

```
formControl!:FormControl
@Input('formControl') set _formControl(value:AbstractControl){
      this.formControl=value as FormControl;
}
```

In this way  you can use `[formControl]="registerForm.controls['email']"`

Comment: Thanks for answer but still facing some issues :/  
1) Still not displaying under the email label that the "email is already taken".

2) Where exactly to use this code: `formControl!:FormControl
@Input('formControl') set _formControl(value:AbstractControl){
      this.formControl=value as FormControl;
}` ? In text-input.component.ts or register.component.ts? 

I tried in both but got an error: `Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<any>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange`

Comment: Using [value] works as well - binding numbers to gender. Still fighting with valiadtion errors.